# Graphs of two functions related by conjugation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function.

Consider $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{4}f(4x).$

Note that the map $h:t\mapsto 4t$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is conjugation of $f$ by this homeomorphism (i.e. $g= h^{1-}fh$).

In short, $f,g$ are similar/conjugate functions in the language of linear algebra. Since, similar transformations share many common properties (trace, determinant, characteristic polynomial, etc.), this raised a natural question:

> **Q.** Which properties are common for $f,g$ when defined in above way. How their graphs differ?

Comment: Well, it's the graph of $f$ "zoomed out" by a factor of $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of $f(4x)$ is the graph of $f(x)$, but squished by a factor of $4$ along the $x$ axis.

The graph of $\frac14 f(x)$ is the graph of $f(x)$, but squished by a factor of $4$ along the $y$ axis.

---

Therefore, the graph of $g$ is the same as the graph of $f$, but shrunk by a factor of $4$ along *both* dimensions, i.e. it looks like the graph of $f$, but zoomed out.

Comment: Very nice. I was trying to plot graphs and see it, for *non-linear* $f$; but I was not getting the visualization. Can you suggest some non-linear $f$ for which it is easy to draw graphs of $f,g$?

Comment: @Beginner Any function should do, so long as you know how to draw it. I would try quadratics, or $e^x$, or $\sin$.